# Cut granite in home...help?

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, countertops, granite, dust

I unintentionally allowed a contractor to cut granite (24 sq in) in our home without proper ventilation. There was a 30 minute dust plume, followed by dust settling all over the first floor. I have recently become aware that granite dust has toxic respirable crystalline silica in it. I wore an N95 and stopped the process when I realized what a disaster I had created.

So is this a burn the house down scenario? I hired a cleaning crew to clean the house aggressively while running a huge industrial hepa rated air scrubber.

What more actions should I take? I occasionally see some sand like shiny particles on the hardwood. Should I have the vents cleaned? Am I screwed? House ruined? I have seen some internet horror stories and I am in a bad place right now.

Edit: I'm in a bad place because the women here appear to have burned their houses down and died... https://www.houzz.com/discussions/2679721/cutting-granite-on-site .....

Comment: what are you talking about? ... the link says nothing about houses burning down and people dying

Comment: Read the comments. Abatement companies, Silicosis, destruction.

Comment: House is ruined! Nuke it from orbit, it's the only way!! Or, take a deep breath (outside, if preferred), relax, and clean your house. You've had someone come in and do a deep clean, but there will still be some dust around, but you'll be fine. You may want to get HEPA filters for your furnace for a while, and you might want to get yourself a fancy HEPA filtered vacuum, but just keep cleaning. Of course, it was pretty rude of the contractor to cut that inside - if they do stone work for a living, they should have known better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~ 20 years ago, I decided to replace my oven. My old (broken) oven was a single ~ 24" oven in a brick wall. My new oven is a double 27" oven. So that meant cutting out bricks, blocks, concrete, etc. with my electrician's heavy-duty tools, followed by a cuts on the left and right with a diamond blade saw.

In case you are wondering, most people in my neighborhood with the same original 1950s builder-installed oven simply replaced it with a storage cabinet in the brick wall and put a bigger oven elsewhere in the kitchen. But I was determined!

Debris from hand-sized chunks down to (un)breathable dust everywhere. For several Sundays - sending my wife and 1-year-old out of the house for a few hours each time. It was an ordeal. Each time, and especially at the end of it all, the shop-vac got a workout. We survived. My electrician came in and ran the new wires and installed the breaker and the ovens worked great.

You'll be fine. Is cutting granite inside a **good** idea: No. But clean it up and you'll be fine. Not to suggest doing such things, but even asbestos is not really so bad as a "one time" exposure - the problem is breathing it repeatedly day after day, year after year.

You did the right things - stop when you knew there was a problem, clean thoroughly and HEPA air filtration. When you find more of the dust, wipe it up with a damp cloth and you should get most of it.

Comment: Feeling better already - this is what we've been doing. Finding little sand bits here and there and wiping it up. The initial cleanup was a beast. Should we get the ducts cleaned or just change the filters?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with duct cleaning for this. Within a relatively short amount of time, the *loose* dust will be gone and the stuff that sticks to the ducts ain't going anywhere. Yes change the filters more frequently as long as they keep getting clogged with dust. But other than that, I wouldn't do much after the initial cleaning.

Comment: The only reason I was considering cleaning them was I Saw fair amount of particulate that matched the granite dust within the duct after changing the filter the first time. It sounds like though that any airborne particulate was already sucked up by my scrubber in the first day, at the remainder has just settled into the ducts and will remain there.

Comment: Also my garage is still a dusty mess. Can I lift weights in there still?

Comment: If the garage is still a mess, I would give a once over with a good shopvac. Whatever it doesn't suck up isn't likely to get blown around by regular air circulation.